# Translating a draconic bloodrager from Pathfinder to 5E

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-5e, character-creation, conversion

I am planning a summer campaign.  I have a player with whom I have played some 5e recently, but who currently plays Pathfinder and has played Shadowrun in the past.

One of the characters he has played in Pathfinder is a draconic bloodrager.  He likes the character concept and wants to implement something similar in 5e and is looking for some guidance.

I am not a Pathfinder player, but I have looked at the Pathfinder SRD and I am not seeing that there is a 5E equivalent to the PF draconic bloodrager.

The draconic bloodrager seems something like a 5th Edition multi-classed berserker/eldritch knight/draconic sorceror, only a barbarian can't cast spells while raging, which seems contrary to the PF bloodrager.

Can anyone provide me with some guidance to pass on to this player?

Comment: Are you open to homebrew solutions? (I don't have any, but I imagine a barbarian archetype might work for this.)

Comment: I'm open to homebrew.  I might suggest to the player that if he really wants to invest in this idea that he might think about suggesting a homebrew.  But my concern is that the draconic bloodrager seems to combine a set of things that weren't intended to go together in 5e.  A berzerker casting magic, an eldritch knight raging, or a tank draconic sorceror all seem a bit contradictory.  Also, in a general sense I am trying to keep the campaign fairly close to RAW and I have some concern that allowing one player to homebrew a special class will cause a disturbance in the force.

Comment: @Jack *I have some concern that allowing one player to homebrew a special class will cause a disturbance in the force*  Have you discussed with this player the idea of simply playing what's in 5e?  (As an RP player I usually see a red flag for players who play the same thing ... stuck in a rut, as it were.  It broadens the experience to try a variety of classes and challenges ... but some people need to be nudged that way to have the light go on).

Comment: @KorvinStarmast That is a good point.  The player basically said, can 5e do this? and I was stumped a bit.  It's possible the answer is maybe it can, but try playing something else.

Answer (score 1):

5e Actually currently cannot do this, for the reasons mentioned in @Jack's answer, rules as written.

There are options though:

- A class feature can be modified on a rare or higher rarity magic item.
- The player can multiclass into Barbarian from Eldrich Knight and have to make choices between raging and casting
- Ask the other players at the table if they're comfortable with this change being made, and if they're all in agreement proceed with caution.
- Say no.

All of these are valid options, but I reccommend the first.  Rare items generally take a pretty serious quest to obtain, and that could be a lot of fun for the entire party, if it aligns with their goals.  Heck, put it on a Battleaxe.  Make his day.